# Vue Jest testing an element's inline style

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

**How to get a style property of an html element in Vuejs + Jest test?**

Using `jest` and `@vue/test-utils` to test if a textarea element has `color` inline style applied in Vuejs.

I have set `ref` on the textarea and the tests for checking the textarea existance and its value were successful but failed to get the `color` property from the style of the element.

Below is my component and test code:

```html
<template>
    <Post :post="post">
        <QuestionCard ref="questioncard" :background="post.background">
            <textarea
                ref="posttext"
                :style="{ color: post.color }"
                class="text-center"
                v-model="post.text"
                disabled
            />
        </QuestionCard>
    </Post>
</template>

<script>
import Post from './Includes/Post';
import QuestionCard from '~/components/Posts/Includes/QuestionCard';
import { FeedPost } from '~/classes/FeedPost';

export default {
    name: 'SingleItemPost',
    components: {
        Post,
        QuestionCard,
    },
    props: {
        post: {
            type: FeedPost,
            required: true,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

```js
import { Wrapper, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import QuestionPost from '../QuestionPost.vue';
import { FeedPost } from '~/classes/FeedPost';

Wrapper.prototype.ref = function (id) {
    return this.find({ ref: id });
};

describe('QuestionPost', () => {
    let wrapper;
    let post;
    const text = 'text';
    const color = 'color';

    beforeEach(() => {
        post = new FeedPost({
            text,
            color,
            type: 'questionPost',
        });
        wrapper = shallowMount(QuestionPost, {
            propsData: {
                post,
            },
        });
    });

    it('should render correct elements', () => {
        expect(wrapper.ref('questioncard').exists()).toBe(true); // OK
        expect(wrapper.ref('posttext').exists()).toBe(true); // OK
    });

    it('should have correct value and style', () => {
        const textarea = wrapper.ref('posttext');
        expect(textarea.element.value).toBe(text); // OK
        expect(textarea.element.style.getPropertyValue('color')).toBe(color); // failed
    });
});
```

I tried it with `textarea.element.style.color` as well, but same.

The test result:

```
Expected: "color"
Received: ""
```

**So how can I get the `color` of the textarea element?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because the test is setting in invalid color value (i.e., `"color"` is not a valid value for the `color` style), so the setting is silently rejected.

To resolve the issue, choose one of the valid [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) values (e.g., `"red"` or `"#090"`).